# hold in "Trying to load lib" and no return for ever

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a old app written by C++, I am trying to port it to `android`, and debug it with eclipse, but the project is stopping with an error message :

**10-03 12:21:55.344: D/dalvikvm(15262): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.android.test/lib/libtest.so 0x40effa48**

The application just stops without giving any other message. I don't know how to do continue.

Comment: post code for `libtest.so`....

Comment: no, Im the newer for ndk, dont know the JNI_OnLoad... But all of the samples in ndk haven't too. Is it necessary for init?

Comment: and, what's mean "post code for libtest.so"?

Comment: JNI_OnLoad is optional, I asked this question because wrong code in it could cause the reported symptoms.

Comment: Have you got some global objects that use nontrivial constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem but it is caused by this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43819)

So simply remove NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7 from your Application.mk i have this only on Android 2.2 with android-ndk-r8e

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following function to you library:

```
#include <jni.h>
jint JNI_OnLoad( JavaVM* vm, void* reserved )
{
    JNIEnv* jEnv = NULL;

if ( JNI_OK != ( *vm )->GetEnv( vm, (void**)&jEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_4 ) ){
    return -1;
}
return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
```

}

*updated:* absence of JNI_OnLoad() is not a problem...

 You have written in comment that You have lots of global initers - consider do such global initializations in JNI_OnLoad()


*Signatures*:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_android_test_testLib
 * Method:    init
 * Signature: (II)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_test_testLib_init
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

/*
 * Class:     com_android_test_testLib
 * Method:    uninit
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_test_testLib_uninit
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     com_android_test_testLib
 * Method:    touch
 * Signature: (IIII)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_test_testLib_touch
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint, jint, jint);

/*
 * Class:     com_android_test_testLib
 * Method:    update
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_test_testLib_update
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

Comment: I found a new problem, when connected ndk-gdb, the eclipse console printed:

Comment: "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.", but I run ndk-build with DEBUG, and the manifest xml setup debug=true too. the libtest.so also with 20MB size, I think it should be a debug version

Comment: For gdb, you must specify the symbols separately, so the behaviour is OK

Comment: en, Im sure the JNI_OnLoad not called. I think maybe some global init functions was failured, but my code have many global initers. I hope a method that can coursed my C++ code crash and tell me the crash position

Comment: Would You mind to show you load library code? and is Your library or one of library it depends is not ported to android?

Comment: package com.android.test;

import android.util.Log;

public class testLib {

     static {
      try {
       System.loadLibrary("test");
      } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       Log.e("testLib", "Load libtest.so failured");
      }
     }

     public static native void init(int width, int height);
     public static native void uninit();
     public static native void touch(int type, int x, int y, int which);
     public static native void update();
}

Comment: no, I have merged all the code compiled, so, only this library

Comment: does your native functions match the following signatures ? see ansver

Comment: [@user1716020](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1716020/user1716020): you can add **__android_log_print** to all global initializers.